# Передать данные из HTML в JS

Tags: javascript, html

У меня есть определённая задача: взять из страницы HTML файл, который загрузил пользователь (это будет текст форматов .txt или .json), а в другом файле js считать этот файл и записать в переменную. 
Нужно или чтобы из html передавало в js или чтобы запоминался путь который выбрал пользователь, а потом в js задать этот же путь.

HTML:

```
<h1>Выберите файл!</h1>
<div class="custom-file">
    <input type="file" class="custom-file-input" id="customFile">
    <label class="custom-file-label" for="customFile">Choosefile</label>
</div>
```

Подробнее опишите связку HTML -> JS и обратно, как взаимодействовать, желательно без ajex, jquery и прочих.

P.s Это разрабатывается не для браузера, а программы на ПК.

Заранее спасибо!

Comment: А причём тут си?

Answer (score 1):

Вам нужно работать с объектом `FileReader`. А саму операцию чтения файла производить в обработчике события `onchange`

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  const fileInput = document.getElementById('customFile');

  fileInput.addEventListener('change', function() {
    const selectedFile = fileInput.files[0];
    const reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = function(e) {
      console.log(e.target.result);
    };

    reader.readAsText(selectedFile);
  });
});
```

```html
<h1>Выберите файл!</h1>
<div class="custom-file">
  <input type="file" class="custom-file-input" id="customFile">
  <label class="custom-file-label" for="customFile">Choosefile</label>
</div>
```